# In a finite state Markov Chain $p_{ij}^{(n)}\le M\lambda^n$

Tags: markov-chains, transition-matrix

> In a finite state Markov Chain , show that there exists $M>0$ and $0<\lambda<1$ such that for all the transient states $i$ and $j$ , we have $$p_{ij}^{(n)}\le M\lambda^n$$

I guess $\lambda$ should be something like $\max\limits_{i,j\in S}p_{ij}$ (I might be wrong) , but I have no clue abut $M$.

$S$ is set of transient states

Comment: I would suggest to delete $0$ from before $\lambda$. Or to insert a < sign.

Comment: @zoli Aha.. typo